# Proofs in discrete mathematics

Tags: proof-writing

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+, r\in \mathbb{N}^+, s\in \mathbb{N}^+, r\cdot s \leq n \implies r \leq \sqrt{n} $ or $s \leq \sqrt{n}$

Assuming that $\mathbb{N}^+$ refers to all positive natural numbers starting at $1$. 
Can someone pls give me a hint as to how to start this proof? I'm not too sure on how I should approach this.

Comment: You could try proof by contradiction.

Comment: assuming not true.. easy to do now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem. If $r \le s $ then $r^2 \le rs \le n$. So $r^2 \le n$ and $r \le \sqrt{n}$. And similarly if $s \le r $ then $s \le \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: How did you get  r≤s if r = s?

Comment: The case $r = s$ is included in the argument as well with the $ \le $ symbol....Most folks would use contradiction proof as commented above, and I tried hard...to be slightly new....

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I don't really understand your method. It's a bit too confusing for me. So far, I have tried to use contradiction where rs≤n implies n≤r or n≤s, then I mutliply the right side for n≤rs, which contradicts the left side... Could you verify if this is right?

Comment: I also tried contraposition where I rearranged it to be $ r  > \sqrt{n}$ or $ s > \sqrt{n} \implies rs > n$, then rs > n $\implies$ rs>n

Comment: Yours must be both of inequalities lead to $rs > n$ which is a contradict to given.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong.

Assume the statement is false:

(The negation, hopefully correct).

There exists an $n\in \mathbb{N^+},$  $r,s \in \mathbb{N^+},$

such that $rs \le n$  implies

$r \gt √n$ and $s\gt √n.$

Then: $ n \ge rs \gt n,$ a contradiction .